# Maven dependencies not visible under Build path in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Luna for my project. I've imported a Maven project into it. Right click->import->import existing maven projects.  I made mvn clean package install under run configurations. It ran successfully till mid of project, and in the sub modules, it got failed due to some issue in Java file. But whatever the JAR's that have been fetched should be displayed under Maven dependencies under Build path right?

Here is the screenshot [image]

Do I require to make any steps here?

Comment: What is the error you get when you ran mvn clean install ?..it seems the dependencies are not fetched from the package repository and hence not available

Comment: @saurav, few dependencies are fetched. install got failed in the middle of sub modules, rest of the other dependencies should be there, isn't it?

Comment: maybe the missing dependencies are stored in repositories other than the default repository

Comment: which repository? they are available in .m2 repository.

Comment: `.m2` is not a repository. It is the place where `settings.xml` should be located, your personal configuration directory on the local machine. By default, the local maven repository is located in `.m2/repository` , but you can change this in `settings.xml`. When maven doesn't find a dependency in the local repository, it searches in the remote repositories. The default remote repository is [http://repo1.maven.org/maven/](http://repo1.maven.org/maven/). If you have to use artifacts (dependencies) which are not published in the default repo, you have add this repository to your POM

Comment: Do you already see the dependencies which are fetched in the local .m2 repo ?

Comment: @saurav, I'm not able to see the dependencies under build path, but they are available in .m2 repo

Answer (score -1):

Right click the project and Configure as Maven project

Comment: @Syed - did you check this for **every** sub module?

Comment: @Ulrich, yes I checked